# click outside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<body>
    <div id="aaa">
       <div id="bbb">
       </div>
    </div>
</body>


$(#?????).click(function(){

     $('#bbb').hide();

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GkRY2/

What i must use if i want hide #bbb if user click outside box #bbb? But if i click on div #bbb then box is still visible - only outside.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 $('body').click(function(e){
       if( e.target.id == 'bbb' )
          { return true; }
       else
          { $('#bbb').hide(); }

 });
```

A note of explanation: There are a few ways to do this, either way we need to listen for a click on a parent element, weather it be a direct parent like `#aaa` or a distant parent like the `body` or the `document`. This way we can capture clicks that occur outside of `#bbb`.

Now that we have that we need the `.hide` to NOT occur if the user did click inside of `#bbb`. We can do this two ways

1. Stop propagation if the user clicks on `#bbb`. This will make the click event not **['bubble'](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)** up to the parent. That way the click event never reaches the parent and so `#bbb` will not hide. I personally don't like this method because stop propagation will so ALL click events from bubbling, and you may have click events that you would like to bubble to a local parent and not a distant parent. Or you may have listeners delegated from a distant parent, which will stop working if click propagation is stopped.
2. Check for the `#bbb` element in the parent listener. This is the method shown above. Basically this listens on a distant parent, and when a click occurs it checks to see if that click is on `#bbb` specifically. If it IS NOT on `#bbb` `.hide` is fired, otherwise it returns true, so other things that may be tied into the `click` event will continue working. I prefer this method for that reason alone, but secondarily its a-little bit more readable and understandable.

Finally the manner in which you check to see if the click originated at `#bbb` you have many options. Any will work, the pattern is the real meat of this thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/tpBq4/ //Modded from @Raminson who's answer is very similar.

---

New suggestion, leverage event bubbling without jQuery.

```
var isOutSide = true
    bbb       = documment.getElementById('bbb');
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){
   if(!isOutSide){
       bbb.style.display = 'none';
   }
   isOutSide = true;
});

bbb.addEventListener('click', function(){
   isOutSide = false;
});
```

Comment: Good answer but there was an extra parenthesis outside the if conditional ending click() prematurely.

Comment: After I removed the last parenthesis here "if( e.target.id == 'bbb') )" it was good to go. I closes the click function too soon from what I see. The last line is supposed to be where the click function ends. With that parenthesis it doesn't work. Maybe I'm seeing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 4):

Catch the `click` event as it bubbles-up to the `document` element. When it hits the `document` element, hide the element. Then in a `click` event handler for the element, stop the propagation of the event so it doesn't reach the `document` element:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', function () {
        $('#bbb').hide();
    });
    $('#bbb').on('click', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KVXNL/

Docs for `event.stopPropagation()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 2):

I made a plugin that does this. It preserves the value for `this` where as these other solutions' `this` value will refer to `document`.

https://github.com/tylercrompton/clickOut

Use:

```
$('#bbb').clickOut(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `target` property of the event object, try the following:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id != 'bbb') { 
          $('#bbb').hide();
    }
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GkRY2/6/)

Comment: No need to create a jQuery object out of `e.target`... `e.target.id` will work just fine.

Comment: I didn't vote but it's funny that yours is the only answer that got any play and it got one up and one down vote...

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
$("#aaa").click(function(){

     $('#bbb').hide();

});

$("#bbb").click(function(event){

    event.stopPropagation();
})​
```

Becouse *bbb* is inside the *aaa* the event will "bubbel up to *aaa*". So you have to stop the bubbling by using the  `event.stopPropagation` when *bbb* is clicked

http://jsfiddle.net/GkRY2/5/

Answer (score 0):

OK

***  this is none jquery. you can easly modify it to work with IE

first create helper method to facilitate codding don't get confused with JQuery $()

```
    function $g(element) {

    return document.getElementById(element);

    }
```

create our listener class

```
  function globalClickEventListener(obj){

    this.fire = function(event){
        obj.onOutSideClick(event);
        }
    }
```

let's say we need to capture every click on document body

so we need to create listeners array and initialize our work. This method will be called on load

```
      function initialize(){

    // $g('body') will return reference to our document body. parameter 'body' is the id of our document body

    $g('body').globalClickEventListeners = new Array();
    $g('body').addGlobalClickEventListener = function (listener)
    {
        $g('body').globalClickEventListeners.push(listener);

    }

    //  capture onclick event on document body and inform all listeners

    $g('body').onclick = function(event) {
        for(var i =0;i < $g('body').globalClickEventListeners.length; i++){
            $g('body').globalClickEventListeners[i].fire(event);
        }
    }

}
```

after initialization we create event listener and pass reference of the object that needs to know every clcik on our document

```
    function goListening(){

        var icanSeeEveryClick = $g('myid');
        var lsnr = new globalClickEventListener(icanSeeEveryClick);

       // add our listener to listeners array   

        $g('body').addGlobalClickEventListener(lsnr);

       // add event handling method to div   

        icanSeeEveryClick.onOutSideClick = function (event){
             alert('Element with id : ' + event.target.id + ' has been clicked');
        }

    }
```

*** Take into account the document body height and width

*** Remove event listeners when you don't need them

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('#elementId').length) {
        if($('#elementId').is(":visible")) {
            $('#elementId').hide('fast');
        }
    }        
})
```

Change the "#elementId" with  your div.